# Select query issue with join

Tags: mysql, select, join

Hello please help me for this one,

```
stent table
```

[image]

```
bal table
```

[image]

with stent_size 20 from both table, current_status = co_qc_comeplete and status = added, i would like to get only 5 records, instead that in my select query i got 50 recrods.. i am confused..

I want only 5 records of stent table with join of bal table and want to get any 5 records from bal table.

Can anyone help me to create select query for this one..

Thanks in advance..

---

Edit :

```
select * from stent as sd 
left join bal as bd on sd.stent_size = bd.stent_size 
where sd.current_status = "CO_QC_Complete" 
  and sd.stent_size = "20" 
  and bd.status = "added"
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: `my select query i got 50 records`? Well, can we see that?

Comment: Edited query in question.

Comment: You aren't making this easy for us, but it looks like you're missing a join on ID.

Comment: sql queries do not work the way you suggest: if your join condition basically is the `stent_size` value, you effectively get the cross product. the bal table contents do not make sense, the part you show at least appears to be massively redundant. can you supply more info on your data model?

Comment: Can you add what records you expect to return

Comment: If you select specific columns from `bal`, and leave out the `ID` column, then you can use `DISTINCT` to filter out the duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar this would give him one result as the rest of the data is not unique

Comment: Everything in the `bal` table looks like duplicates except for `id`.

Comment: exactly, which is why this query is not great and this table setup is not great

Comment: @jt. see the update to my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from stent as sd 
left join bal as bd on sd.stent_size = bd.stent_size 
where sd.current_status = "CO_QC_Complete" 
and sd.stent_size = "20" 
and bd.status = "added"
```

Returns 50 records because it takes all of bal (10 records shown) and joins stent (5 records shown) where stent_size = stent_size.  (Each bal record is paired with all five stent records)

There is nothing unique about your data save the ids, so this can be trouble when joining these tables.

Thinking about this a little more, and I think I get what you are wanting.

Try this:

```
 Select Distinct st.id, st.stent_material, st.stent_size, st.stock_qty, st.current_status, 
 bal.diameter, bal.lot_no, bal.quantity, bal.received_from, bal.expiry_date,
 bal.status, bal.created_date, bal.modified_date from stent st
 INNER JOIN bal ON bal.stent_size = st. stent_size
 where st.current_status = "CO_QC_Complete" 
 and st.stent_size = "20" 
 and bal.status = "added"
```

Comment: That being helpful.. thanks Marshall. next time i'll keep it in mind before creating table structure..